# SQL - How to transpose or pivot columns from different tables

Tags: sql, pivot, hiveql, transpose

Table 1:

```
Primary_Key | City | Zip
1           | A    | A
2           | C    | D
```

**Note: the masked value under City or Zip can be the same, in this example, "A" will show up in both City and Zip.**

Table 2:

```
Col_Name | Lookup_Key | Value
City     | A          |Seattle
Zip      | A          |70895
City     | C          |Chicago
Zip      | D          |60604
```

I want to create a 3rd table based on table 1 and table 2 to get below:

```
Primary_Key | City    | Zip
1           | Seattle | 70895
2           | Chicago | 60604
```

Can someone help to write a SQL that can return above result?  The real table have much more records than this example.

(I am not sure if the question title is reflecting what I am really asking, please share if you have better question title suggestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend two joins:

```
SELECT t1.Primary_Key, tc.Value as City, tz.Value as Zip
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 tc
     ON tc.Lookup_Key = t1.City AND tc.col_name = 'City' LEFT JOIN
     table2 tz
     ON tc.Lookup_Key = t1.Zip AND tz.col_name = 'Zip';
```

Hive should be able to handle this quite well -- as well as other databases.

Comment: this query seems will create duplicates "Primary Key" columns.

Comment: @azCats . . . Well, by definition, a "primary key" is unique in the table where it is defined.  Duplicates could only arise from the `left join`s, and that would only happen if there were lookup keys with the same *value* and *col_name*.  That seems quite unlikely to me, given the question.

Comment: thanks Gordon, I think that is the issue. In fact the Lookup Keys in table 2 could have same value across different col_name.   The lookup key is like a sequence number and it will reset on each col_name so there will be overlap.

Comment: @azCats . . . So what?  Both the `lookup_key` and `col_name` are used for the `join` and the pair should be unique -- as it is in the sample data in your question.

Comment: sorry I checked again,  your answer seems correct..  Somehow I found @GMB answer has the duplicate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    t1.Primary_Key,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Col_Name = 'City' THEN t2.Value END) City,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Col_Name = 'Zip' THEN t2.Value END) Zip
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Lookup_Key IN (t1.City, t1.Zip)
GROUP BY t1.Primary_Key
```

This **[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ECaSBD75nNGQ7gMfw4B9h/0)** with your sample data returns :

```
| Primary_Key | City    | Zip   |
| ----------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1           | Seattle | 70895 |
| 2           | Chicago | 60604 |
```

Comment: is there something missing in the join condition?  "ON t2.Lookup_Key = t1."

Comment: @azCats : yep, just fixed it, and I added a link to a db fiddle too, so you can see the query in action.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot..  I have one concern, because the value (masked) of  t1.City and t1.Zip in can the same, would that inner join create duplicates?  In this example, how does the SQL tell the masked "A" belongs to City or Zip?

Comment: @azCats : you will not get duplicates, since the outer query aggregates the results. The trick happens in the `MAX()` functions, where the actual `Col_Name` is checked.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I tried use your query against the real table, it worked but the query performance seems little bit slow..  The other user [Gordon Linoff]'s  "two joins" code seems faster however it does not return the correct result..  do you think if the "two joins" option [Gordon Linoff] suggested can really work for this problem?

Comment: @azCats : this you would have to ask Gordon... I used aggregation to avoid duplicates when `table1.City` = `table1.Zip`, and this is where his query seems to have issues.

Comment: Hi @GMB,  I checked Gordon's code again,  it looks like his code actually is correct but yours has the duplicate issue.  When I say "duplicate", it means your query returns different PKs for same City & Zip.  (in this example I used City instead of "domain" which is in the real data,  basically the combination of domain & Zip will have unique PK, hope this does not confuse you)..   I think the possible issue might be in this part "ON t2.Lookup_Key IN (t1.City, t1.Zip)"

Comment: Hi @GMB, the trick part is in real data, I have about 25k rows.  I have 5 columns,  (PK, domain, zip, city, state).  Domain+Zip make the PK unique.     I believe because the example only have 2 rows,  your code actually worked..  but when I extended to the real data, your code return some rows correctly but some rows incorrectly.. interesting..

Comment: I think I figured it out.  See my edited code in your answer.  that actually solve the issue.